# Gradle: Burning actual dependencies versions in release branch

Tags: java, gradle, release, dependency-management

In my team we develop several applications, all use the same in-house framework. This framework is separated to many sub modules, each with its own version, and each is published as a jar to artifactory (maven repository).

When we release an application we create a branch for it and we want to compile that branch against the latest release of each framework module (that's ok because in our nightly regressions we compile against the latest snapshot). We use gradle so this is done by setting the dependency version as "latest.release". This works great until we need to fix a bugs in production - then we release a patch for the released application by checking out the release branch, fixing the bug, compiling, validating and packaging the app.

Problem: latest.release now points to a different release version than the one we originally compiled against.

What I want: when releasing the app, burn all its resolved versions (the resolved latest.release) on the build.gradle (or in some other file) so when I compile it again in the future I will compile against the old releases.

I assume many developers face this issue, yet I haven't found any solution for this online. I never used maven but while searching for a solution I discovered there's a plugin in maven, release plugin, that does exactly what I need.

Would like to know if you have a solution for this problem.

Comment: Netflix has a plugin that does this: https://github.com/nebula-plugins/gradle-dependency-lock-plugin

Comment: @RaGe looks promising! will check that out. thanks.

Comment: @RaGe that's exactly what I needed! Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Netflix has a plugin that handles locking dependency versions at releast time: https://github.com/nebula-plugins/gradle-dependency-lock-plugin
2. Alternatively, you can use this plugin: https://github.com/ben-manes/gradle-versions-plugin to identify dependencies that have newer versions, and replace them manually as needed.

Comment: Now Gradle 4.8+ has this feature in-built. They just released the shenzi!
https://docs.gradle.org/4.8/release-notes.html